# Why when i export a 3D model in blender and the model have texture it doesn't export the texture too

Tags: texturing, export, .fbx

I have a 3D model for earth and it has **alot of texture for clouds,nightlights,topography and earht color**
I did everything **in the node** **in the shading** but when i try to export the earth model it just export it **without any textures**

[image]

this one is for **colors,topography and nightlights**

[image]

and this one is for **clouds**

i saw some people say that every texture must be connected to the **Principled BSDF** but I don't know how to do it here and if there is any way to export it with textures without be linked to Principled BSDF i will be glad to know
and **THANK YOU**

Comment: Hello, I think .obj can't contain images, while .fbx can, also the material needs to be basic, like Image Textures node plugged into the Principled BSDF, but I doubt what you show is compatible with .obj or .fbx